# Is the order of dependencies deterministic in psake?

Tags: psake

```
task A -depends B, C, D { ... }
task B { ... }
task C { ... }
task D { ... }
```

Is build script guaranteed to run in this order?

```
(B - C - D) - A
```

Or backwards?

```
(D - C - B) - A
```

Or random?

```
(B - D - C) - A
```

Or in parallel?

```
B
 \
  \
C--A
  /
 /
D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented as `foreach` so  the first one is garanteed.

Comment: But is there any specifcation tahta states it or it is just the current implementation?

Comment: It is current implementation, but I don't think it will be changed.